# Is it possible to find the closed-form expression for $\int_{\alpha}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-At}}{\left(1+ Bt\right)t^m}dt$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is it possible find the closed-form expression or represent it in other function for this integral:
\begin{align}
   I= \int \limits_{\alpha}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-At}}{\left(1+ Bt\right)t^m}dt
\end{align}
where $A, B, m, \alpha >1$. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $m$ is supposed to be an integer.
Let $$I_m = \int_\alpha^\infty \dfrac{e^{-At}}{(1+Bt)t^m}\; dt$$
Note that $$B I_m +  I_{m+1} = \int_\alpha^\infty \dfrac{e^{-At}}{t^{m+1}}\; dt = J_{m+1}$$
where

$$ J_m = \int_{\alpha}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-At}}{t^m}\; dt = \alpha^{1-m} \int_{1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-A\alpha s}}{s^m}\; ds  = \alpha^{1-m} E_m(A\alpha)$$

and $E_m$ is the generalized exponential integral function (this could also be expressed in terms of the incomplete Gamma function).  For $m=1$ we have
$$ I_1 = E_1(A\alpha) - e^{A/B} E_1( A\alpha + A/B)$$
and then 
$$ I_m = (-B)^{m-1} (E_1(A\alpha) - e^{A/B} E_1(A\alpha + A/B)) + \sum_{k=2}^m \dfrac{(-B)^{m-k}}{\alpha^{k-1}} E_k(A\alpha) $$

Comment: Billion thanks for your help!!!!!!!!!!